# How can I add cardview to my android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been having this problem for a long time.
ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview
Affected Modules: app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.self"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: You can check correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` to your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the layout design part and select design oy now in the search (left side of page) search for card view. If that isn't downloaded you'll find a download symbol right next to it. Click on it and this will add the following dependency
`com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"** this dependency in your **build.gradle (Module:app)**

In your layout file:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```