# Android Studio : card view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

I have a problem with Android Studio , i can't add card view to my application and this error happening.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453437/how-can-i-add-cardview-to-my-android-studio-project/61453478#61453478